# To know file size beforehand in JS

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the file size of the file being submitted before the upload actually starts on Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know about this, but you can have a look at this previous post on SO:

[how validate file size using HTML and Javascript on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832415/how-validate-file-size-using-html-and-javascript-on-client-side)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not reliably possible due to security restrictions. You'll need Flash or Java Applet for this. If your intent is just to have a progress bar, have a look at [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/)

Comment: Looks like those are free apps.  What do you mean by "limited resources?"

Comment: Buth are truly free. Where did I said "limited resources"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the not recommended activex (source: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=330134):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
   function A()
   {
    var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var d = document.a.b.value;
    var e = oas.getFile(d);
    var f = e.size;
    alert(f + " bytes");
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="a">
   <input type="file" name="b">
   <input type="button" name="c" value="SIZE" onClick="A();">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The dead should stay burried.

Comment: Can I down vote on principle? Seriously... I know you're trying to be helpful, but ActiveX? I don't think so.  Java or Flash will work cross browser which is a nice feature.  Some people say Java should die but there are still "some" good uses for it.

Comment: I added the "not recommended" before activex :)

Comment: That should not be possible on IE with default config.

Comment: I tested it, and after several warnings from IE, it worked. Didn't work at all in chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant feature (The HTML5? File API or what to call it) that is needed isn't fully specified yet. Mozillas implementation can be read [at the mozilla developer center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File)