# Validate file size using java script

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to validate file size, which I am trying to upload by a File Upload Control.
To validate the size of the file, I am using java script code. But it is throwing run time error. Please somebody help me.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getSize() {
        var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
        var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
        var size = thefile.size / (1024 * 1024);
        alert(size + "MB");
    }
</script>
```

Error message : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Automation server can't create object

Comment: you can have look at this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832415/how-validate-file-size-using-html-and-javascript-on-client-side>

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has no access to the filesystem so its not possible to check the size of the file by javascript.

and

`new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");` - is supported by IE only so do check you are suing IE not other browser.

Check this : [How to validate upload file size and file extension using JavaScript ?](http://deepeshdarshan.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/how-to-validate-upload-file-size-and-file-extension-using-javascript/)

Comment: True, you only can with html5.

Answer (score 0):

File size can only be retrieved in browsers other than IE while using Javascript..