# How to validate file size from clientside using javascript in IE 7/8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-upload

Currently I am using

```
if(navigator.appName=='Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
        if(component.value){
            var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var e = oas.getFile(component.value);
            var size = e.size;
        }
    }
```

to validate the file size.

Is there any other way to validate the size

```
Automation server can't create object error is displayed
```

I know it has something to do with Enabling ActiveX Controls in Settings, but thats not going to happen because one cant control client side system and IE7/8 doesnot even support file Api

Comment: that is so NOT working fine in all browsers but IE...

Comment: What ? i checked the code in IE7, IE8... it gives the error

Comment: how are you getting the file?

Comment: Yea sorry my mistake about that, I had put that code for IE only

Comment: Please check the updated question now

Comment: well, in new browsers, component.files[0].size works if you have a file input...

Comment: actually its IE8 and the thing is I need it to be working in all IE versions, because the client could be using any browser

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/1832497/448407 . Also you should have Activex enabled in the browser.

Comment: Well, thats the same thing I am implementing, but I cannot enable ActiveX on client side

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support this feature

I had found a great plugin for file upload [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: well ActiveXObject feature is made specifically for IE

Comment: +1 for recommending this plugin, however it does not perform so well in IE 7 regarding file size stuff, it takes a lot of time !!

Answer (score 1):

Only IE 9 is not Supporting this Feature.

All Other IE Versions >9 have no Issues.

You can Resolve your issue By applying filter for IE 9 and get file size.
use Below code in else condition for other browsers as per Below.

```
if (browserInfo.indexOf("msie") > -1) 
    {
        /* IE */
        var filepath = document.getElementById('idControl').value;
        if(browserInfo.indexOf("msie 9") == -1)
        {
            var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            if (filepath == "") {
                alert("Please Select File");
                $("#selectorID").attr("src", $("#Contenturlprifix").val() + "/content/img/NoPhoto.png");
                return false;
            }
            file = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
            filetype = document.getElementById('idControl').accept
        }

    } else {
        /* Other */
        file = document.getElementById('idControl').files[0];
        if (file == undefined) {
            alert("Please Select File");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            filetype = file.type;
        }
    }
    if (file != undefined) {
        //10mb size 
        if (file.size / 1024 > 10240) {
            alert("size Exists");
            return false;
        }
        else if (filetype.indexOf('image/') == -1) {
            alert("Select only images");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS............

- Go to internet options.
- Select security tab.
- Under Custom level.
- Ensure that "Initialize and script active x controls is not marked safe for scripting"  select the radio button enabled and  try to run your code now, I am sure your problem will be solved.

Comment: Practically if you are building a web application then you can not ask every customer to do so. Solution should be generic.